# fill dynamic image field with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, image

i have dynamic div setups as follow .

```
    var max_fields_limit      = 5; 
            var x = 0; 
            $('#add_more_button').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                if(x < max_fields_limit){ 
                    x++; 

           $('.new_custom_field').append(
'<div>'+
'<div id="main_row" class="form-group row justify-content-md-center">'+
'<div class="text-center">'+
'<img id="image_pre'+x+'" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20200%20200%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_169f7db97f3%20text%20%7B%20fill%3Argba(255%2C255%2C255%2C.75)%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A10pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_169f7db97f3%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%2275.5%22%20y%3D%22104.8%22%3E200x200%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" class="rounded image_pre" alt="...">'+
'</div></div>'+
'<div class="form-group row">'+
'<label for="c-password" class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-form-label">Product Url</label>'+
'<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6 input_fields_container">'+
'<input type="text" name="product[]" class="form-control"  required>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="form-group row">'+
 '<label for="c-password" class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-form-label">Image Url</label>'+
 '<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6 input_fields_container">'+
'<input type="text" id="inputimg'+x+'"" name="productimg[]" class="form-control inputimg" required>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="form-group col-md-12 text-center">'+ 
'<a class="btn btn-danger remove_button">'+
'<i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>'+
'<div>'+
'</div>');
```

Result from alert  :   image_pre'+x+'  = image_pre1

```
$('.new_custom_field').on('click', '.inputimg', function(e){
        var id = $('.image_pre').attr("id");
      var inputVal = $(this).val();
       alert(id);
     // $('#'+id).attr('src', inputVal).fadeIn();
    });
```

every time i change image from  dynamic row  i found same result in alert. basically i want unique id every time .

Comment: where is inputimg in your html?

Comment: $('.new_custom_field').on('click', '.inputimg', function(e){  i am not seeing inputimg anywhere in your code then how the event is triggred

Comment: see my updated code ..

Comment: Now check my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code,hope it helps

```js
var max_fields_limit      = 5; 
    var x = 0; 
    $('#add_more_button').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields_limit){ 
        x++; 
 $('.new_custom_field').append(
'<div>'+
'<div id="main_row" class="form-group row justify-content-md-center">'+
'<div class="text-center">'+
'<img id="image_pre'+x+'" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20200%20200%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_169f7db97f3%20text%20%7B%20fill%3Argba(255%2C255%2C255%2C.75)%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A10pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_169f7db97f3%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%2275.5%22%20y%3D%22104.8%22%3E200x200%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" class="rounded image_pre" alt="...">'+
'</div></div>'+
'<div class="form-group row">'+
'<label for="c-password" class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-form-label">Product Url</label>'+
'<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6 input_fields_container">'+
'<input type="text" name="product[]" class="form-control"  required>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="form-group row">'+
 '<label for="c-password" class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-form-label">Image Url</label>'+
 '<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6 input_fields_container">'+
'<input type="text" id="inputimg'+x+'"" name="productimg[]" class="form-control inputimg" data-id="image_pre'+x+'" required>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="form-group col-md-12 text-center">'+ 
'<a class="btn btn-danger remove_button">'+
'<i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>'+
'<div>'+
'</div>');

}
})
   $('.new_custom_field').on('click', '.inputimg', function(e){
       var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
       alert(id);
      $('#'+id).attr('src', inputVal).fadeIn();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="new_custom_field"></div>
<button id="add_more_button">Add</button>
```

Comment: @Riteshshirsat check now,I modified your html a bit

Comment: great  nice idea .